# ExpressJS Post request not redirecting user upon submission

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post, redirect

I am creating a webapp using NodeJS and ExpressJS, I have a login form on my website that when completed, sends a post request to the server. The server handles this request and finds them in the MongoDB database, it even attaches the session key as a cookie and the user ends up receiving that, but they are not being redirected to the dashboard page, or even redirected at all. Their session does not time out and the browser is not waiting on a response.

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res){
    var email = req.body.email;
    var password = req.body.password;

    User.findOne({'email' : email}, function(err, user){
        if (err)
        {
            console.log(err);
        }
        if (user)
        {
            var hash = user.password;
            if (passwordManagement.verifyPassword(password, hash))
            {
                var newSession = webSession.generateKey(email)
                webSession.SessionKeys.push(newSession);
                res.cookie('session', newSession.key);
                res.redirect('/dashboard')
            }
        }
        else
        {
            res.redirect('/login');
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some control path issues present in your code.

1. You are not exiting, if there is an error with finding the user by email.
2. You are not doing anything, if user present for the email, but password does not match.

You might want to rewrite as follows:

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res, next){
    var email = req.body.email;
    var password = req.body.password;

    User.findOne({'email' : email}, function(err, user){
        if (err)
        {
            console.log(err);
            return next(err);
        }

        if(!user) {
          return res.redirect('/login');
        }
        var hash = user.password;
        if (!passwordManagement.verifyPassword(password, hash))
        {
           return res.redirect('/login');
        }

        var newSession = webSession.generateKey(email)
        webSession.SessionKeys.push(newSession);
        res.cookie('session', newSession.key);
        res.redirect('/dashboard')
    })
});
```

Note that, I have added `next` parameter to route handler & using it in case of error. Plus, I have rewritten the code for better readability.